# If statement with coordinates (vb)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, integer, point

I have this code and it has an error on the `if carloc = (250,524)` part. The code is to check if the car (picturebox) is somewhere then to move ti somewhere else when you push 'A'. Here's the code:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim carloc As Point
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
     Select e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.A
            If carloc = (250,524) then
                carloc = New Point(285, 524)
                car.Location = carloc
            End If

    End Select
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to check the coordinates individually:

```
If carloc.X = 250 AndAlso carloc.Y = 524 Then
    carloc = New Point(285, 524)
    ' ....
```

If you're dealing with a value type (`Structure`), which you are in this case, or if the type implements `IEquatable(Of T)`, you can also write:

```
If carloc = New Point(250, 524) Then
    carloc = New Point(285, 524)
    ' ....
```

This will work *in this case*, but not as a general rule for any type.

Comment: Cleaner is 'If carloc = New Point(250, 524) Then'

Comment: @AMissico Yeah, but not in a general purpose case... The type needs to implement equality in a meaningful way (does here, since it's a struct, though)

Comment: @AMissico Edited to include that option